# My Django project can't import shortcuts (Pylint Import Error)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

**Unable to import 'django.shortcuts'pylint(import-error)** how can i solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install pylint-django and add this config to your ide:

vscode example in `settings.json`

```
{
...
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_django"
],
...
}
```